# Node Red pass form fields values into msg.payload

Tags: node-red

I have time form with two fields: hour and minutes 
on submit a need to send msg contins the fields values like this {h:12,m:45}

what is the code that I need to put into function node[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to include the output from the debug (set to complete message not just `msg.payload`) node wired directly to the Form node so we can see what the inputs are.

Answer (score 0):

The Dashboard-UI Form node will return a `msg.payload` containing the data as you want it. e.g. in this case

```
msg.payload = { h: 12, m: 45 }
```

Normally you would not need to move these to be fields on the `msg` object as most nodes expect input to be in the `msg.payload`, but if you really want to then you can use a `change` node to move values around in the object. This will be more efficient than using a `function` node.